# Azure AD App Registration error: The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application

Tags: azure-active-directory

Sorry that my question might be repetitive but none of the solutions provided in other links have resolved my issue. Below is my situation

We have ASP.NET Core 3.1 Web application to which we are trying to use Azure AD so that users can login with our Enterprise Credentials. We started with ASP.CRORE MVC default template and enabled to Use Organization credentials and Authentication is working in our Local environment. We are now trying to deploy this app to other internal environments. So we have deployed this to two of our internal servers and configured IIS to refer this website with http IP's assigned. I was able to create Azure App registry for this application and was able to add the http IP's through Manifest, added the clientId to the appsettings.json file and the authentication is working if we refer the website using the http IP's. I have also tried by assigning https IP's assigned to the same websites and added them to Azure App Registry and again the authentication is still working if we refer the website with either of the 2 https IP's.
Now we have decided to create URL something like https://ourwebsitename.companyname.com which resolves to either of the http IP's using F5 Load balancer. I was able to add the URL to the azure app registry and using the same clientId in appsettings.json in the same way how the app is working with http or https IPs. But somehow when we refer the website URL
https://ourwebsitename.companyname.com we are getting the error as mentioned in the title of the question and I did observed after I hit the URL, its getting redirected as redirect_uri=httpXXXX instead of https which I thought may be the reason of the issue but unable to resolve. I have googled it and tried with various solutions but none resolved and so I am posing it again hoping for a luck if someone can provide me a solution.

Following are the links which appeared close to my situation but didn't work for me

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/proxy-load-balancer?view=aspnetcore-5.0
https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/issues/115

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the redirect_ url you configured in the code exactly the same as the one you configured in the Azure portal?  check.

Comment: Hello, my code is something similar to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-aspnet-core-webapp. I didn't get what you meant by "redirect_ url you configured in the code " but still I tried by giving that key in appsettings.json with value similar to what I have provided in App Registration and no luck

Comment: You mean you did not configure `redirect_ url` in the code?

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the sample you provided, and it does not provide the `redirect_ url` key in `appsettings.json`. So, based on my experience, it should have a built-in `redirect_ url`. Otherwise, the **aadsts50011** error will not be reported.

To deal with this kind of problem, you can try a general solution:

When you visit the application url , you will be redirected to the login page. Decode the authorization request url, you will find `redirect_url`, copy the value of `redirect_url` and paste it into the azure portal, and try again.

[image]

[image]

For the redirect URL, it should start with `https`, if you need to start with `http`, you must configure it as `http://localhost`.

Comment: I have followed what you have specified already with same result. Our URL was configured as https and so I provided https URL in Azure Authentication page when I hit the URL it somehow shows redirect_url starting with http in browser. I have changed to http in Azure Authentication using the manifest section. Now when I hit the URL I am getting unexpected error message and an error logged in event viewer of our webserver. Below is the error message. An error was encountered while handling the remote login.  System.Exception: OpenIdConnectAuthenticationHandler: message.State is null or empty.

Comment: @P.N.V.KRISHNAMOHAN  Is only the difference between `http` and `https`? Are the others the same?

Comment: @P.N.V.KRISHNAMOHAN  Also, have you tried using other browsers?

Comment: Yes I tried in all the browsers and it's still the same. Yes like i mentioned as per the URL in browser it shows http:    //websitename.companyname.com/signin-oidc, even though I registered in Azure app Registry as https 
  ://websitename.companyname.com/signin-oidc. If i Change Azure App Registry to http    ://websitename.companyname.com/signin-oidc there is an unhandled excpetion like I mentioned message:state is null